# MS Access: Count instances over field based on record-level criteria

Tags: ms-access

I need a query to count the number of orders shipped to each state for each customer.  So, let's say John had 5 orders: 2 to Florida, 2 to Alaska, and 1 to Kansas.  How do I get those counts for each Customer.  I have a query that provides me Customer and Order delivery state, but I cannot figure out how to get the counts.  I am looking for something like:

```
>John FL 2
>John FL 2
>John AK 2
>John KS 1
>John AK 2
>...[Next Customer]...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group it by customer and state and count based on this:

```
SELECT Customer, State, Count(*) AS Amount
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Customer, State
```

The resulting calculated field, is named `Amount` in this example.

Comment: As you provide, it works.  Thank you!  However, when I try to apply to my query, it falls apart and I get counts of 1 for every record.  Does this work if I have additional fields not included in the "group by"?  For example, using the above, what if the query's SELECT also includes ProductNo and ProductSize?

Comment: It would be best, if you show us your table layout and your current query. Best with sample data and expected result

Comment: The mentioned fields `ProductNo` and `ProductSize` are in the same table I expect? So think about, what happens when grouping like in my query is applied. Which records `ProductNo` and `ProductSize` should be shown? The `First`, `Last`, `Min`, `Max`, `Count`, `Avg` (Average) for example are possible cases.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far.  The desired output would have one row per order-product-size as opposed to "rolling up" to a first, last, etc. The following query is where the count on the state field breaks down.  If I remove OrderProduct then it does work as you provided.  And I get why it falls apart with it included, but I need to find a solution to include and get the aggregated count on the state.  So, I need the output as follows but the state counts aggregated so all of the "1"s become the applicable counts (FL=2, AK=2, etc).

Comment: SELECT tblOrder.OrderCustomer, tblOrder.OrderShipmentDestination, Count(*) AS Amount, tblOrder.OrderProduct
FROM tblOrder
GROUP BY tblOrder.OrderCustomer, tblOrder.OrderShipmentDestination, tblOrder.OrderProduct;